# How do I get the value of an Array without knowing the name of the Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, javascript-objects, bcrypt

im currently working on a user authentication system using expressJS. Therefore to encrypt my data I am using bcrypt. Then I save the encrypted data to a MySQL Database. Then when logging in I get the saved password using `SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE email=${emailUserEntered}`. Well that works but it gives me this output:

```
[
  {
    password: '$2b$10$MyvQenconTHygpwbY/1ExampleHashYju2i8Bq'
  }
]
```

My code:

```
  let userPassword = await db.promise().query(`SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.email}';`);
  const data = userPassword[0].password;
  console.log(data)


  var result = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data);
  if (result) {
    res.send('SUCCESS!');
  } else {
    res.send('WRONG!');
  }
```

How can only get the actual hash as a String and not the brackets and all that?
Thanks in advance, have a nice day

Comment: Sorry, completely misunderstood. When you get that result, save it to a variable. Arrays don't have names anyway. From the variable, you want `whatever[0].password`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work... That gives me the output: undefined

Comment: It would help if you would post the actual code you're attempting.

Comment: Im sorry... just added it

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with that code. If you `console.log(userPassword)` after the `await` line, it shows the structure you first posted?

Comment: exactly... and i want only the hash as a string. Not the entire structure around it

Comment: Yes I understand (now), it doesn't really make sense that the code wouldn't work as written unless the Node console is being weird.

Comment: Well, still thanks for all the help. You have a good one m8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your library's `query()` might be returning a `[rows, fields]` array.
[`mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)'s `query()` does, at least.

Maybe the below?:

```js
  let [rows, fields] = await db.promise().query(`SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.email}';`);
  const password = rows[0].password;
  console.log(password)
```

**Warning**: also, the above code may potentially lead to a frightful [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) depending on what may hide under the `req.body.email`. Please take a look at the [Prepared Statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-prepared-statements) to mitigate this. More info: [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks).

Comment: Omg thank you so much man. Thats exactly it! Keep it up and have a good one

Comment: @BenBöckmann: glad to help! Please also watch out for a potential SQL injection in there .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using JavaScript, so you can do something like that

```
const {password} = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SQL_QUERY_RES).then(items=>items[0])
```

or

```
const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SQL_QUERY_RES))[0].password
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work... They both give the output: undefined

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this output. Try using console.log here,

Comment: @BenBöckmann I have updated the above code, please try now

Comment: Thanks man but that wasnt it unfortunately... I now get the error: ```JSON.stringify is not a function```